# vuejs - i18n : translate pieces of text stored in database

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internationalization, vuejs3, vue-i18n

I have a very long text stored in database and i want to translate a piece dynamically.

for exemple i want to translate only "**Donec venenatis posuere**" of this text how can i do this ?

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. **Donec venenatis posuere** sapien nec bibendum. Vestibulum sagittis efficitur lorem vitae consectetur. Etiam nisl purus, facilisis et scelerisque convallis, vehicula eget ex. Cras tempor, libero et dapibus laoreet, justo massa mattis purus, eu fermentum lectus elit vitae mi. Maecenas feugiat sed tortor sed tincidunt. Suspendisse potenti. Sed aliquet neque nulla, nec finibus lacus iaculis faucibus. Integer non ante mattis, ornare sem eget, consectetur dolor. Integer nec diam sed ante interdum convallis. Sed porta neque sed mattis gravida. Nam rutrum ac erat a facilisis. Quisque dignissim commodo enim, quis efficitur ante tincidunt in. Nunc pellentesque, mauris sit amet porta aliquet, magna elit ultrices lectus, at cursus arcu ligula non enim. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam eget interdum mauris. Pellentesque varius purus sit amet ex venenatis cursus. "

Comment: As per my understanding, instead of this text `Donec venenatis posuere`, it should be a placeholder in the data base `{0}` and while binding that into HTML, it should be replaced with the language literal by using `$t` library.

Comment: You totaly understand.

I don't use the library to translate a site, but to dynamically update the label, site title, ...

my client changes his mind every 3 days.

Comment: So in that case what you can do is, in HTML you can do a translation like that `<i18n path="<dbString>"><b>Donec venenatis posuere</b></i18n>`